# Magento 2 Xdebug PHPStorm JIT does it work for Fatal Errors?

Tags: magento2, xdebug

Has anybody got JIT xdebug to work in Magento 2 with PHPStorm, is it compatible? I have regular debugging with breakpoints working fine, but JIT will not work I get a Fatal Error like this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource in C:\WTServer\WWW\mage23update\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php:50 Stack trace: #0 C:\WTServer\WWW\mage23update\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...') #1 C:\WTServer\WWW\mage23update\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(167): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...') #2 C:\WTServer\WWW\mage23update\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(273): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'resource', 'Itoris\\DynamicP...') #3 C:\WTServer\WWW\mage23update\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(236): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument('Itoris\\ in C:\WTServer\WWW\mage23update\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php on line 50
```

and have JIT enabled in php.ini for Xdebug but it does not break. I also enabled the xdebug logs and nothing is logged, but the logs work fine when using breakpoints. Php.ini:

```
zend_extension = "php_xdebug"
xdebug.remote_mode = "jit" 
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
```